# Breaking MsBuild package & deploy into separate MsBuild and MsDeploy commands

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm having a few problems breaking out an MsBuild package+deploy command into two separate commands. (I need to do this to pass additional parameters to MsDeploy).

The command that works fine looks like this:

```
msbuild "src\Solution.sln" 
  /P:Configuration=Deploy-Staging 
  /P:DeployOnBuild=True
  /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
  /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://192.168.0.1:8172/MsDeploy.axd
  /P:DeployIISAppPath=staging.website.com 
  /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
  /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WmSvc 
  /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
  /P:UserName=staging-deploy 
  /P:Password=xyz
```

The separated packaging command looks like this:

```
msbuild "src\Solution.sln" 
  /P:Configuration=Deploy-Staging 
  /P:DeployOnBuild=True
  /P:DeployTarget=Package 
  /P:_PackageTempDir=C:\temp\web
```

which works fine. But then the MsDeploy portion:

```
msdeploy 
 -verb:sync 
 -allowUntrusted 
 -usechecksum
 -source:manifest=
  'src\WebProject\obj\Deploy-Staging\Package\WebProject.SourceManifest.xml'  
 -dest:auto,ComputerName=
  'https://192.168.0.1:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=staging.website.com',
   username='staging-deploy',password='xyz',authType='basic',includeAcls='false'
 -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

fails, with the following error in WmSvc.log

```
wmsvc.exe Error: 0 : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
setAcl/C:\temp\web (Read)
ProcessId=15784
ThreadId=31
DateTime=2011-03-30T14:57:02.4867689Z
Timestamp=3802908721815
wmsvc.exe Error: 0 : Not authorized.
Details: No rule was found that could authorize user 'staging-deploy', 
         provider 'setAcl', operation 'Read', path 'C:\temp\web'.
```

(and several more Read/Write operations)

Something is clearly going wrong with the paths it's trying to access (as it works fine with the other method) - I'm not sure it's even trying to use the iisApp targeting correctly, and at the moment I don't think the correct web.config's will be deployed either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've got this fixed now - I needed a different command to the one the automatically generated .cmd file was using, but comparing the two allowed me to fix it up (thanks @Vishal R. Joshi)

The differences I needed was:

- basic authentication
- allow untrusted certificates
- ?site=staging.webserver on the end of the MsBuild.axd path, as with my original command
- override the IIS Web App name that is set in the params file
- enable the do not delete rule

The winning command is as follows:

```
msdeploy 
 -verb:sync 
 -allowUntrusted 
 -source:package='src\WebProject\obj\Deploy-Staging\Package\WebProject.zip'  
 -dest:auto,ComputerName=
  'https://192.168.0.1:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=staging.website.com',
  username='staging-deploy',password='xyz',authType='basic',includeAcls='false'
  setParamFile:
    "src\WebProject\obj\Deploy-Staging\Package\WebProject.SetParameters.xml"
 -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='staging.website.com'
 -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
 -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension 
 -disableLink:CertificateExtension
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: James, is this msdeploy command generated by myproj.deploy.cmd file or is it hand crafted?
Thanks
Vishal R. Joshi | http://vishalrjoshi.com | http://twitter.com/vishalrjoshi

Comment: hey Vishal, not quite - the problem with the deploy.cmd command is that: I need to set basic auth, and I had to add ?site=staging.webserver as a parameter on the target computer name, as the user does not have permission to access all of IIS That said, I've managed to get this working now - turns out I should have been using source:package rather than source:manifest (I think it was trying to create a package using the manifest definition on the destination server rather than locally - my own misunderstanding of how it would work).

Answer (score 1):

Add a delegation rule on the server using inetmgr to allow staging-deploy to carry out set-Acl operations.
Inetmgr -> Click on server node -> Management Service Delegation (in Management) -> Click Add rule to the right -> Choose the template labelled "Set Permissions for Applications" -> Accept defaults and click OK.

This should let you deploy any package or manifest with setAcl as long as the user you are deploying as, has permissions to the site you are deploying to.

Comment: Thanks Owais, but it already has a setAcl permission for that user (along with contentPath, createApp and iisApp). Also, surely calling msdeploy directly (if i'm doing it correctly!) would require the same server side permissions as the msbuild route - and that works completely fine...

Answer (score 0):

You are able to specify the **-setParam:name='',value=''** flag when calling the MyProject.deploy.cmd file that is created when you generate a Package from a web project. The cmd is a friendly wrapper around msdeploy.exe, so you have no need to specify all the rest of the defaults.

Here's the details: http://evolutionarydeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/specifying-environment-variables-at.html