# Disabling the "Remove additional files at destination" property when using AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml Template for CI builds

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml Template for CI builds and it's working great.

However, I need to keep additional files on the server (the app creates files). If I was using the "Web deploy" method, I'd simply disable the "Remove additional files at destination" property, but I don't see an option for that using the Azure deployment template.

Do I need to create a publish profile and associate it with the template? I see there's an option to add one in the template settings, but it seems odd that it would be necessary for this.

Update: According to this thread: [Valid Parameters for MSDeploy via MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598668/valid-parameters-for-msdeploy-via-msbuild)

I should be able to add /p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True to the MSBuild arguments in the build definition, but it isn't working. Files are still being deleted from the web server when I deploy

Comment: I was in the opposite situation, I wanted my unversioned files deleted.
I had to edit my build definition to disable 'Do Not Delete', see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13809851/stackoverflow/AzureContinuousDeploy_Clean.png.  Maybe your setting is set to true?

Comment: The above comment link is 404