# Azure Build task for Windows Service :- no zip under $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have an azure pipeline which produces a zip artifact in  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory). Later we extract this and deploy to target folder. This works fine with websites. The msbuildargs looks like below :-

```
msbuildArgs : '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
```

We have a windows service which is not generating any zip artifact. After following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153600/vsts-directory-d-a-1-a-is-empty-nothing-will-be-added-to-build-artifact-dr). I added /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory) in msbuildargs, Now I can see the files, but no zip file. Which we actually use.

```
msbuildArgs : '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:OutputPath="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
```

is there any csproj settings for zip artifact? any specific setting for windows service ? Could not find more documents for PackageAsSingleFile.

Comment: What is your project type? Could you generated the .zip with those MSBuild arguments in your local without Azure devops?

Comment: It is windows service targeting .net framework 4.8 (Console App). I am not able to generate zip on local as well.

Comment: Yes, That seems only way. I am working on it. would mark resolved once get it done. Thanks

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any csproj settings for zip artifact? any specific setting for windows service ? Could not find more documents for PackageAsSingleFile.

Most of your MSBuild arguments are apply to ASP .NET projects and will do nothing for a  windows service (Console App).

We just need to use `/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. That will tell MSBuild to put the build outputs in the artifact staging directory.

But this still will not generate zip package with the argument `/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. If you want to to generate zip, we could use the task [Archive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops).

Besides, we could change the `/p:OutDir` to other folder, so that we could use Archive files task to generate zip, like:

```
/p:OutDir=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/output
```

Then use the archive file task:

[image]