# MSBuild MSDeploy from within VS2010 Build Definition

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy

We are currently using Team Foundation Server Build Definitions to build our solution and now I want to add deployment to that.  We are using TFS Build servers out of the box for our builds.  Currently, we are deploying the web app to our dev integration servers using Web Deploy (MSDeploy) from within VS2010 (Publish on the toolbar).  The desire is to move this publish to the build server.

What is the best approach to be able to reuse the MSDeploy mechanism (since it's already in place on IIS) and have the build server take over that task?  Can I use MSBuild params or do I need an MSBuild project file?  How would I configure the appropriate approach in the Build Definition?  It is unclear how to configure a Publish using a Build Definition and MSDeploy.

P.S. I've seen several mentions of MSBuild using MSDeploy with cmd line params, but not in the context of using a Team Explorer Build Definition.

Some links to pages that I've seen, but are incomplete based on my needs:
[Creating a Build Definition That Supports Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/creating-a-build-definition-that-supports-deployment)
[How to Publish Web with msbuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild)

Comment: Consider adopting a tool designed for performing releases instead of over-extending the build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ALM Rangers' Building Guidance](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/) has all the information you are looking for, in particular the chapter "Deployment of Applications and Data Stores".

Comment: what I was looking for - specifically pages 193/194 of the "Build Customization Guide.pdf".  Also, this SO post was useful as well for all available args: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5598737/156611

Comment: Oh, and this SO post as well - very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5867846/156611