# Missing files from bin folder after azure zip deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, webdeploy

I am using azure build pipelines  to deploy my custom solution into an existing one, but after deployment some dlls from the existing solution get removed, I am using zip deploy method and after some research I found **this method will delete files that were part of a previous deployment and are not in The deployment artifact**.

[image]

based on [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) here for zip deploy, it says : **Deletion of files that were left over from earlier deployments.**

It is a module that needs to be deployed on top of existing solution that has other modules as well, so i don't need other dlls to be removed, I just want to deploy my solution dlls on top of an existing one. any idea how this can be done ?

Comment: Is it this option?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32080567/724039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Zip deployment doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push. When you use .zip deployment, any files from an existing deployment that aren't found in the .zip file are deleted from your function app.

You could try using "Web Deploy" method and disable "Remove additional files at destination" option.

[image]

Also, you could use "Exclude files from the App_Data folder" with additional arguments to prevent files in the App_Data folder from being deployed to or deleted from the Azure App Service. Refer to this ticket for details: [Azure Pipelines: Exclude folders using Azure App Service Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537030/azure-pipelines-exclude-folders-using-azure-app-service-deploy)