# How do I specify Web Deploy Providers in my Publish Profile?

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am running an msbuild command that I point to a Publish Profile.

Here is a snippet of the publish profile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://mysexyserver:8172</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>MysexyApp</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <UserName>mydom\myuser</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
    .....
```

I want to use the [createApp provider](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522996(v=ws.10).aspx) so when I deploy to the server it automatically creates my app pool and iis site.

Where do I specify I want to use the createApp provider? Do I put it under the ProperyGroup node in the publish profile? Do I pass it as an arg to the msbuild command? Haven't found any clear examples of this I can figure out.

Is there an option instead  of DeployIisAppPath that will use the createApp web deploy provider to automatically create the site and app pool???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use it as an argument to the msdeploy command:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:createapp="Default Web Site/MyCreatedApp" -dest:auto
```

---

See valid msdeploy properties in msbuild: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598737/1093508

The best you can try is **DeployIisAppPath**:

```
<DeployIisAppPath>createapp="Default Web Site/MyCreatedApp"</DeployIisAppPath>
```

Comment: That's not the msbuild command that the msdeploy command. How do I do this from msbuild

Comment: How do I pass that source parameter to msdeploy from msbuild? Can I put that in the publish profile???

Comment: Does the DeployIisAppPath help? (see the edited answer)

Comment: i cant find any documentation using it that way, have you tested that?