# Where can I find the documentation for the different msbuildargs options?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am in the process of creating a build pipeline. I have a `vsBuild@1` step and I am trying to see what options I could use in the `msBuildArgs`. I have looked at multiple links such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019 but couldn't find the different fields or arguments I could set, such as `'/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true`.

Where can I find the documentation for all of those options?

Comment: `/p=xx` is a build project property. The common ones are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Hi Hussam, did you get a chance to implement the solution that Leo suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find the documentation for the different msbuildargs options?

There is no such document to list all msbuildargs for MSBuild. MSBuild does not have a complete list of parameters you can chose from since you can send any parameter you like. It is a means of communication between the caller of MSBuild and the author of the MSBuild build script (a vs sln or csproj file for instance).

msbuildargs usually contains some [common properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019), but also contains some attributes specific to specific build action, for example, `deploy: DeployOnBuild` [MSBuild Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/gg433487(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). And it also contains the properties in the publish file or our custom `.targets` files.

Therefore, in addition to some commonly used attributes, msbuildargs has more attributes related to the action of MSBuild and the type of project being built. Currently, there is no complete list for it.

Some commonly used MSBuild properties:

[Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019)

[MSBuild Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/gg433487(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019)

[Parameters for MSDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598668/valid-parameters-for-msdeploy-via-msbuild)

And so on.